# python kivy How to save my textfle into internal storage(file manager)

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to save a simple text file in internal storage via android apk which was created by python kivy.
I want to create a directory in internal storage and save my textfile in it.
Please help me to fix.I lost with it.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You need to handle `Android Permissions` (`WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) and choose a folder where the user has permission to write.

Comment: Thank you John Anderson for your fast response.However I don't have an external storage in my Android Can't I access my internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

you can use file stream to create a file to a specific path

```
#if it is a txt file
f = open('<enter your path here>/filname.txt',"w")
f.write(data)
f.close()

#if it is a any other file
import pickle
f = open('<enter your path here>/filname.ext',"wb") #ext can be pdf,jpg,png etc
pickle.dump(f,data)
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you so much  for your response but however it's not my problem,I could write when i was using my linux,my need is to create a folder in my internal storage via my android application and store the text file or whatever else in it.

Comment: can you post the code in order to understand the issue. Also, what response are you getting at the moment ?